# Delete row of cells, but not the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to only delete cells 7B:7G, while leaving 7A alone. How do I do this using excel VBA?

Here is the code I have now:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wsIMP As Worksheet 'Import
    Dim wsTOT As Worksheet 'Total
    Dim wsSHI As Worksheet 'Shipped
    Dim wsEST As Worksheet 'Estimate
    Dim wsISS As Worksheet 'Issued
    Dim cel As Range

    Set wsIMP = Sheets("Import")
    Set wsTOT = Sheets("Total")
    Set wsSHI = Sheets("Shipped")
    Set wsEST = Sheets("Estimate")
    Set wsISS = Sheets("Issued")

    With wsIMP

        wsIMP.Range("E6").Cut wsIMP.Range("E5")
        wsIMP.Range("B7:G7").Delete (xlShiftUp)

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to delete range `B7:G7`, shifting cells left or up (depending on requirements):

```
range("B7:G7").delete(xlShiftToLeft)
```

or

```
range("B7:G7").delete(xlShiftUp)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using With, you shouldn't mention wsIMP in 2 middle lines. Change your code to:

```
With wsIMP

    .Range("E6").Cut .Range("E5")
    .Range("B7:G7").Delete (xlShiftUp)

End With
```

also notice 2nd range notation. It's B7:G7 not 7B:7G

Comment: I actually did this: `Range("B7:G7").Delete xlShiftUp` and it works perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don't put . in front of Range..., then macro will use activesheet instead of wsIMP. It may be important if you intend to use macro in sheets other than active sheet